# Assets destination folder is not set Skipping react native (Images not loading in the APK)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using this 
command :

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

Output
`Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\mgaba\Desktop\InfraGBU\node_modules (86ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\mgaba\Desktop\InfraGBU\node_modules (94ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
**Assets destination folder is not set, skipping...`**

**Due to this i will not able to see images in apk. Images is not loading with this please help to remove this error.**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try This it worked for me

for android

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

**EDIT**

for ios

`react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

Thank you @kalpa

Comment: I am getting the same error for iOS, Can you guide me what will be the command?

Comment: For iOS : react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

Comment: yes you are right @kalpa 
i forgot to write about `ios`
i'll edit answer
thank you

Comment: This only works sometimes.....I keep ending up with a cached (old) version of my project when I build a release build. Why?

Comment: How to undo this?

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: @JoMomma you need to add --reset-cache to the command to get rid of cached version

Answer (score 3):

In your project directory, open terminal/command prompt and try below commands:

react-native bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/ --entry-file ./index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --platform android --dev false

Then follow below commands:

cd android
./gradlew installRelease or ./gradlew assemblerelease

Please note that, if you have "index.android.js" file then use above commands as it is else replace it with "index.js" and use above commands.